# Is there a way to set the value of a read-only dependency property in the XAML of the control it's defined in?

Tags: .net, wpf, mvvm

Suppose I have a read-only dependency property called MyProperty, which has a public get and a protected setter, is there a way to set an initial value for this property on the XAML of the UserControl?

The problem is two-fold: first you can't directly reference the property on the XAML because the top-level element is  but I've solved that problem with the following trick:

```
<UserControl.Style>
    <Style>
        <Setter Property="local:MyUserControl.MyProperty" Value="{Binding someProperty}" />
    </Style>
</UserControl.Style>
```

This results in

```
The Property Setter 'MyProperty' cannot be set because it does not have an accessible set accessor.
```

Any ideas how to get around this without resorting to code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the basic ideas of (not only) MVVM is to encapsulate the definition of the data *presentation* (View) from the *presented data*. What you're trying to do is not really MVVM style in my opinion. I would consider a data field's default value as something that belongs to the data rather than it's presentation. So, why don't you set the default value in the ViewModel. This makes more sense (think of an hypothetical second View which uses the ViewModel: You still want the same default value) and you don't have any issues. Are there any reasons, you consider the default value to be View-specific and therefor want to define it there?

Secondly, as the other answer says, your approach is quite inconsistent, as you want to set a protected property from the 'outside'.

Answer (score 1):

Protected setters to achieve immutable/readonly dependency properties is not the right way. 
With SetValue and the static Property field the value can still be set. You have to realize that the accessor you are trying to hide is just a convenience (a light wrapper around the public available SetValue).

Did you take a look at this MSDN article:[ReadOnly Dependency Properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms754044.aspx) ? I know it is rather complicated for such a simple scenario, but hey WPF was never mend to be simple.